# vi set default found line to center of screen?

Tags: unix, solaris, vi

Using vi on a Solaris 10 system.  When I search for a string with the common syntax

```
/foo<CR>
```

the placement of the found line is semingly random within the 60 lines on my display.  Sometimes it is near the top, sometimes middle, often the last line.

I would like it to be at a consistent location, (somewhere above the bottom).  The following will always place it in the middle

```
/foo/z.<CR>
```

How can I make that the default behavior so that if I simply type

```
/foo<CR>
```

it will display the found line in the middle every time?

Comment: This Q **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related sites http://superuser.com OR http://vi.stackexchange.com . Consider using the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Thanks and Good Luck

Comment: vi won't scroll when it is not needed. When you have more `foo`'s in the part of the file on the screen, it will jump through them. And how can vi put the line in the middle, when your file only has one line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding in your `~/.vimrc` something like:

```
let g:in_search = 0
function! StartSearch()
  let g:in_search = 1
endfunction

function! EndSearch()
  if g:in_search
    normal! zz
  endif
  let g:in_search = 0
endfunction

nnoremap / <ESC>:call StartSearch()<CR>/
cnoremap <CR> <CR>:call EndSearch()<CR>
nnoremap n nzz
nnoremap N Nzz
```

could do the trick.

But maybe you just need:

```
set incsearch
set hlsearch
```

?!

Comment: vi, not vim, so I created .virc and put your script in.  It seems to work fine, thanks.  (also, no incsearch nor hlsearch available).